# XSLT: variables and "empty" labels

Tags: variables, xslt

I have an XML datafile containing among other things a string of arbitrarily many comma separated values. I want those values to be displayed in a web browser as a list with one value per line. So I wrote an XSLT template that takes this string, displays the first value followed by a linebreak tag (`<br/>`), properly name-spaced, and resources with the remainder of the string. In effect, the commas are being replaced by HTML `<br/>` tags.

Now, when I store the result of calling that template in a `xsl:variable`, and display that through `xsl:value-of`, then the HTML tags disappear: what is shown is the string minus the commas.

When I display the result directly by having the `xsl:call-template` in place of the `xsl:value-of`, all is fine, and the values appear in a list.

So, what's going on?
Is this behavior an implementation artifact, or is it standard XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`xsl:copy-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copy-of) instead of [`xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#value-of) if you want to output nodes (like your `br` elements), `xsl:value-of` creates a simple text node with the string value(s) selected.

Here is an example that shows the difference between `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:copy-of`, you will note that it is not the use of the variable with newly created `br` elements that makes the difference, it is simply the use of `xsl:value-of` that creates a `text()` node with the string conversion of the selection:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:variable name="var">Phrase 1.<br/>Phrase 2.<br/>Phrase 3.</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <section>
              <h1>Example 1: value-of</h1>
              <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
          </section>
          <section>
              <h1>Example 2: copy-of</h1>
              <xsl:copy-of select="$var"/>
          </section>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//p"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//p" mode="copy-of"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
      <section>
          <h1>Example 1: value-of</h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </section>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p" mode="copy-of">
      <section>
          <h1>Example 1: copy-of</h1>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </section>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJy/1

Output is

```
Example 1: value-of
Phrase 1.Phrase 2.Phrase 3.
Example 2: copy-of
Phrase 1.
Phrase 2.
Phrase 3.
Example 1: value-of
Line 1.Line 2.Line 3.
Example 1: copy-of
Line 1.
Line 2.
Line 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you hit the boundaries of the [RTF ("Result tree fragment")](https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/result-tree-fragments-and-node-sets):

> When you use an XML fragment to initialize a variable or a parameter, then the variable or parameter is of the
>     "result tree fragment" datatype. This is an XSLT 1.0 specific datatype [just like node-set, but slightly different]. 
>   A result tree fragment is equivalent to a node-set that contains just the root node.
>   **You cannot apply operators like "/", "//" or predicate on a result tree fragments. They are only applicable for node-set datatypes.**
>   [...]
>   a) In XSLT 1.0
>   The resolution of this is to convert the result tree fragment into a node-set. I am not aware of any oracle specific xpath extension functions that can do this trick for you.
>   You could use EXSLT to achieve this.
>   b) Use XSLT 2.0
>   You can code your transformations in XSLT 2.0.  XSLT 2.0 deprecates ResultTreeFragments i.e. if you are modeling an XSLT 2.0 transformation, and you create a variable or a parameter that holds a tree fragment, it is implicitly a node sequence.

So without using an XSLT version greater than 1, you're out of luck. So better use XSLT-2.0 or 3.0 to solve this problem.

> Is this behavior an implementation artifact, or is it standard XSLT?

It is standard for XSLT-1.0, but not for XSLT-2.0+.

Comment: Well, just to be sure, my problem is solved - by not using that intermediary variable (and it's XSLT-1.0). So obviously there's more going on when using variables to store results from calls to templates than just storing the results, in my case the removal of empty tags.

Comment: @dehulst, you can copy a variable with nodes to the output in all versions of XSLT, but you need to use `<xsl:copy-of select="$variable"/>` to do that, `<xsl:value-of select="$variable"/>` will create a text node with the string value of the variable selection, so that means any nodes like your `br` elements are stripped. That is just how `xsl:value-of` works, even if you selected input elements, you would get a text node with the string value and not the nodes in the output. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#value-of

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. `xsl:value-of `not only generates text, but it also creates a text node in the tree, and as text nodes cannot contain subnodes, any that are present, such as my tags, which are inserted nodes from another tree, are stripped.

Thanks, @Martin.